# Floating list items with zen-grids based layout

Tags: html, css-float, sass, compass-sass, grid-layout

I am trying out [zen-grids](http://zengrids.com/) for a website re-design. I like its general ability to produce a grid based, responsive design without putting everything into extra `<div>`s and adding layout related class names to the tags. I use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)/[Compass](http://compass-style.org/) anyways, so zen-grids is an obvious choice. But I have a hard time to figure out how to best achieve the following "floating list items" effect (e.g. for a typical product grid in a web store):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    ul {
      width:100%;
      list-style-type:none;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }
    li {
      width:25%;
      height:10em;
      background-color: silver;
      float:left;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Say I have a 12 column layout (`$zen-column-count: 12;`), how could I use zen-grids to put four list items covering three grid columns each next to each other into one row? The only possibility I see myself is to use four different CSS `:nth-child` pseudo classes and `@include zen-grid-item(3, [start column here]);`. This rules out all Internet Explorer versions below 9, [lacking implementation](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) of that pseudo class.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Salsa magic

I solved the problem by changing the tools: [Tsachi Shlidor](https://github.com/tsi)'s [Salsa](http://tsi.github.com/Salsa/) is an alternative grid layout system for Sass, which makes the following solution without `:nth-child()` possible. I added a little `respond-to` responsiveness as well.

**style.scss** (compile with compass)

```
@import "salsa/salsa";
$base-font-size: 100%;
$base-line-height: 1.5em;
$container-width: 100%;
$gutter-width: $base-line-height;

@import "respond-to";
$breakpoints: "wide screen" (50em),
              "narrow screen" (0em 50em);


body {
    @include container;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    li {
        height: 10em;
        background-color: silver;
    }
}
/* layout for narrow screens: 2 items per row */
$columns: 8;
@include respond-to('narrow screen') {
    ul {
        li {
            @include grid(4);
        }
    }
}
/* layout for wide screens: 4 items per row */
$columns: 16;
@include respond-to('wide screen') {
    ul {
        li {
            @include grid(4);
        }
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution that does not involve switching from zen grids. I am using drupal zen theme and zen grids is already tied into it. If anyone has one please post!

Answer (score 3):

For those not wanting to switch, I was able to accomplish this using the following mixins:

@include zen-nested-container(); (for the parent container that holds the shopping cart items)

@include zen-grid-flow-item(1, 4, true, true); (for the shopping cart div)

@include zen-float(left); (float the items left to keep them on the same line)

Example SCSS:

```
#block-views-course-dashboard-block-2 {
    @include zen-grid-item(3, 3);
    @include zen-nested-container();
    .views-row {
      @include zen-grid-flow-item(1, 4, true, true);
      @include zen-float(left);
      height: 10em;
    }
}
```

I used Drupal 7 Zen Theme with Zen Grids. See http://zengrids.com/help/#mixins for more information about the arguments for zen-grid-item and zen-grid-flow-item.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with zen-grid, but grid frameworks usually have a *last* class which has no margin-right. This way, you could apply that class to every four elements in your structure.

If you use some CSS framework it could be even easier. As an example, this is what I would do using Compass + Blueprint grid:

```
ul:nth-child(4n) { @include last; }
```

Comment: Good point. I'll have a look at it. Still, the :nth-child() pseudo class does not work in IE < 9. What I have come up with so far (I'll post it if we don't find a better solution), is what I have outlined in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/), [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) and [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) polyfills to enable CSS3 selectors and media queries support in IE 7 and 8.

Note that versions and order of polyfills are important. Follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16732064/901944